# CHEF Use a Not_If to Check if Program is Installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra

I'm trying to make my CHEF script smart enough to not try and install Rails, if it's already installed.  Below is how I'm currently handling it, but it seems like there is probably a better way.

```
execute 'install_rails' do
  user 'root'
  cwd '/root/'
  command "/root/.rbenv/shims/gem install rails -v #{node['rails']['version']}"
  not_if "rails -v | grep \'#{node['rails']['version']}\'"
end
```

Does anyone have any experience with a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the normal `gem_package` resource or the `ruby_gem` resource from poise-ruby?

Comment: Initially, I had tried gem_package but it CHEF kept skipping that resource because it said it was already up-to-date, even though Rails wasn't already installed.  So I went and started doing it the manual way.  Haven't heard of poise-ruby.  I'll check it out.

Comment: If using gem package make sure you set the gem binary path as a resource property so it uses the right ruby.